# Overwrite media matching post title using WP CLI's media import command

Tags: media, wp-cli

I am trying to overwrite a media post using the WordPress CLI.

The `wp post create --post_type=attachment` command can create an empty media item, but cannot attach an image file through **WP-CLI**. This is only possible through the GUI or other **WP PHP** Functions. The CLI command creates a "corrupt" media post. Is it better to avoid using this method?

On the other hand, the `wp media import $filename` command does not include (according the [Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/import/)) fields like `--post_name`,`--post_date` and other `post` fields. This method then requires running `wp post update $id_media` for setting these fields once the post is created.

Hence, it is not possible for `wp media import $filename` to overwrite a Media post that matches on `--post_name`. If you try this, WP actually just creates a duplicate media object, with a new regenerated `--post_name`. This means the `wp post exist` and `wp post delete` process must be done manually as a part of this process.

Is my thinking correct?